# How to run feature specs inside a docker container with capybara & poltergeist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I have a ruby on rails 5 app in which I've written some feature specs, utilizing `capybara` and `poltergeist`. On their own, they run fine - however, when I run them inside a docker container, they explode pretty spectacularly. I'm pretty green when it comes to docker and I am a bit lost in figuring out how to debug this on my own. I've found some resources that utilize `selenium` but not in conjunction with `capybara`.

Here's some configuration files:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:2.4.1

ENV DIR=/app \
    BUNDLE_JOBS=4 \
    PHANTOMJS=phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
ADD https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/$PHANTOMJS.tar.bz2 /
RUN mv ./$PHANTOMJS/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin
RUN rm -rf ./$PHANTOMJS
RUN phantomjs --version

RUN mkdir $DIR
WORKDIR $DIR

ADD Gemfile $DIR/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock $DIR/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
ADD . $DIR

EXPOSE 3000

ADD docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

CMD bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "2"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    env_file:
      - docker.env

  app:
    build: .
    links:
      - db:db
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file: 
      - docker.env
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
```

**rails_helper.rb**

```
docker_ip = %x(/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }').strip
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist_debug do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(
    app,
    debug: true,
    js_errors: true,
    host: docker_ip)
end

# Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist_debug
Capybara.app_host = "http://#{docker_ip}:3000"
Capybara.server_host = '0.0.0.0'
Capybara.server_port = '3000'
```

Whenever I run my feature specs inside my docker container with `docker-compose run --rm -e "RAILS_ENV=test" app rspec`, I typically the following error:

```
36) BookPolicy show? permits non-admins
      Failure/Error:
        TCPServer.open(custom_host || HOST, port || 0).tap do |server|
          @port = server.addr[1]
          @host = server.addr[2]
        end

  Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL:
    Cannot assign requested address - bind(2) for "172.19.0.1" port 0
  # /usr/local/bundle/gems/poltergeist-1.15.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/web_socket_server.rb:34:in `initialize'
  # /usr/local/bundle/gems/poltergeist-1.15.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/web_socket_server.rb:34:in `open'
  # /usr/local/bundle/gems/poltergeist-1.15.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/web_socket_server.rb:34:in `start_server'
  # /usr/local/bundle/gems/poltergeist-1.15.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/web_socket_server.rb:26:in `initialize'
  # /usr/local/bundle/gems/poltergeist-1.15.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/server.rb:25:in `new'
  # /usr/local/bundle/gems/poltergeist-1.15.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/server.rb:25:in `start'
  # /usr/local/bundle/gems/poltergeist-1.15.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/server.rb:9:in `initialize'
  # /usr/local/bundle/gems/poltergeist-1.15.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/driver.rb:40:in `new'
  # /usr/local/bundle/gems/poltergeist-1.15.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/driver.rb:40:in `server'
  # /usr/local/bundle/gems/poltergeist-1.15.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/driver.rb:25:in `browser'
  # /usr/local/bundle/gems/poltergeist-1.15.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/driver.rb:184:in `reset!'
  # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.14.4/lib/capybara/session.rb:127:in `reset!'
  # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.14.4/lib/capybara.rb:314:in `block in reset_sessions!'
  # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.14.4/lib/capybara.rb:314:in `reverse_each'
  # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.14.4/lib/capybara.rb:314:in `reset_sessions!'
  # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.14.4/lib/capybara/rspec.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

---

So what am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

---

Update #1: I removed the `host` config setting the poltergeist driver. The new `rails_helper.rb` config looks like the following:

```
docker_ip = %x(/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }').strip
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist_debug do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(
    app,
    debug: true,
    js_errors: true)
end
```

I now get the following error:

1) admin can update passage page translation via a passage page edit link
     Failure/Error: visit book_cover_path(book)

```
Capybara::Poltergeist::StatusFailError:
   Request to 'http://172.19.0.1:36827/books/the-heart-is-deceitful-above-all-things/cover' failed to reach server, check DNS and/or server status
 # /usr/local/bundle/gems/poltergeist-1.15.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb:377:in `command'
 # /usr/local/bundle/gems/poltergeist-1.15.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb:36:in `visit'
 # /usr/local/bundle/gems/poltergeist-1.15.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/driver.rb:97:in `visit'
 # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.14.4/lib/capybara/session.rb:269:in `visit'
 # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.14.4/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
 # ./spec/features/passage_mode_spec.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

... so now phantomjs can't reach the server, even though it's using the right ip address and the port I exposed in my `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: Can you curl this on your machine `http://172.19.0.1:36827/books/the-heart-is-deceitful-above-all-things/cover` and see if it works?

Comment: Why you need to set host for capybara and poltergeist ?